# ImproperlyConfigured while porting code from Django 1.8 to Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, debugging, refactoring

I am trying to make some project described in a book based on Django 1.8. This part should enroll a student to some course:

**CBV:**

```
class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['enroll_form'] = CourseEnrollForm(initial={'course': self.object})
```

**Form:**

```
class CourseEnrollForm(forms.Form):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**HTML with "Enroll" button** (detail.html)**:**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url "students:student_enroll_course" %}" method="post">
           {{ enroll_form }}
           {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Enroll now">
    </form>
{% else %}
     <a href="{% url "students:student_registration" %}" class="button">Register to enroll</a>
{% endif %}
```

**HTML after successful enrollment** (shortened):

```
{% with subject=course.subject %}
    <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
    <div class="module">
       <h2>Overview</h2>
       <p>
         <a href="{% url "elearning:course_list_subject" subject.slug %}">{{ subject.title }}</a>.
         {{ course.modules.count }} modules.
         Instructor: {{ course.owner.get_full_name }}
       </p>
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

With this I get an error `NoReverseMatch` - next I comment out `<a>` tag - the page loads, but with all empty `{{ }} template variables`. And when I click `Enroll` button - I get:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /students/enroll-course/
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

It looks like a `Course` model instance was not passed into the Django template. But why does this happen? A book says that this code should work. Did something changed in Django 2.0 in those stuff?
**P.S.** If I comment out a `get_context_data` method - a page loads with all template variables as it should, but still `Enroll` button throws the same `ImproperlyConfigured` error.

Comment: We can't help with the `NoReverseMatch` because you haven't shown your urls. I don't think you've shown the view that handles `/students/enroll-course/` either - that's the one that requires `template_name` to be set. Finally, your `get_context_data` should return `context`. Currently it's returning `None`.

Comment: @Alasdair - lol, actually u answered my question :) The only problem was I missed to return `context` :( So shame on me.